# Omitting arguments causes promisified functions to fail for ES2015 classes

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

I'm having trouble getting the [Bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html)'s `promisifyAll` function to work with an ES2015 class's object instance methods when arguments are omitted. I'm using Node 7.8.0. Here's some sample code:

```
// dog.js
class Dog {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.name = opts.name || 'Fido';
  }

  fetchBone(bone, callback) {
    console.log('fetching the bone');
    callback(null, 'got it');
  }
}

exports = module.exports = Dog;
```

Let's say the bone is an optional argument for `fetchBone`. When I pass it, everything's fine.

```
> var Dog = require('./dog');
> Promise = require('bluebird');
> Promise.promisifyAll(Dog); // omitting this line doesn't help
> Promise.promisifyAll(Dog.prototype);
> var puppy = new Dog();
> puppy.fetchBoneAsync('juicy bone')
       .then(result => console.log('from promise:', result))
       .catch(err => console.error('failure:', err));
fetching the bone
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> from promise: got it
```

It fails when I don't pass in the bone.

```
> puppy.fetchBoneAsync()
       .then(result => console.log('from promise:', result))
       .catch(err => console.error('failure:', err));
fetching the bone
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> failure: TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Dog.fetchBone (dog.js:8:5)
    at Dog.tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Dog.ret [as fetchBoneAsync] (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:14:23)
    at repl:1:7
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:339:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:536:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:241:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:590:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:869:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:609:7)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:120:10)
```

Strangely, it works if I pass in `undefined` for the bone.

```
> puppy.fetchBoneAsync(undefined)
       .then(result => console.log('from promise:', result))
       .catch(err => console.error('failure:', err));
fetching the bone
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> from promise: got it
```

Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: `fetchBone()` does not handle variable arguments.  If you code it to work without the first argument being passed, then the promisified version will work too.  The problem is that when you pass only one argument, then `fetchBone()` tries to call the 2nd argument as the callback, but the callback isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that is correct behavior.  The promises are mapped to the original functions.  So `fetchBone()` is receiving two arguments in the first call and one in the second example.

This means that in the second example, when `fetchBone()` is called `callback` is undefined and the `bone` itself is the callback function created by the promisification to handle the promise itself.